# Evaluate: $\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x}(x+y)^2 e^{2y\over x+y}dy dx$.

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

Evaluate:
$$
  \int_0^2\int_0^{2-x}(x+y)^2 e^{2y\over x+y}dy dx.
$$

My attempt: I've changed the order and got this as
$$
  \int_{y=0}^2\int_{x=0}^{2-y}(x+y)^2 e^{2y\over x+y}dy dx.
$$
and then substituted ${2y\over x+y}=t$  so the integral becomes
$$
  8\int_{y=0}^2\int_{t=y}^{2}e^t t^{-4}\,dt\,y^3 dy
$$
from here it's becoming very absurd. Please help me to solve easily from here onward, any other short cut will be very benefited. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By using the change of variables
$$
u = y+x, \\
v = y-x
$$
with inverse transformation
$$
x = \frac{u-v}{2}, \\
y = \frac{u+v}{2}
$$
then the domain can be expressed as
$$
0\leq u\leq 2, \quad -u\leq v\leq u
$$
Taking into account that the Jacobian of the transformation is $J=1/2$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2 du\int_{-u}^{+u} u^2\exp\left(\frac{u-v}{u}\right)dv = 2(e^2-1)
$$

Answer (score 0):

you can just take $t=x+y$ it becomes:
$$
\int_0^2 \int_y^2 t^2 e^{\frac{2y}{t}}dtdy
$$
change the order of integral :
$$
\int_0^2 t^2 \int_0^t e^{\frac{2y}{t}}dy dt = \int_0^t t^2(\frac{t}{2})(e^2-1)dt=(e^2-1)\frac{2^4}{2\times 4} = 2(e^2-1)
$$